# Filtering nested JSON javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, filter

I'm creating an API that takes a JSON like this:

```
 "hightlights":[
  {
     "title":"Fun",
     "url":"fun/index.html",
     "queries":
     [
        "music",
        "artists",
        "events",
        "internet"
     ]
  },
  {
     "title":"Internet",
     "url":"internet/index.html",
     "queries":
     [
        "javascript",
        "web",
        "internet",
     ]
  }
 ]
```

I need to filter the JSON with a word given by user and return with another JSON with only object that contains the word in "queries".

```
 If word === 'music', receive:
 {
     "title":"Fun",
     "url":"fun/index.html",
     "queries":[
        "music",
        "artists",
        "events",
        "internet"
     ]
 }

 If word === 'internet', receive:
 {
     {
     "title":"Fun",
     "url":"fun/index.html",
     "queries":[
        "music",
        "artists",
        "events",
        "internet"
     ]
  },
  {
     "title":"Internet",
     "url":"internet/index.html",
     "queries":[
        "javascript",
        "web",
        "internet",
     ]
  }
```

My problem is how to nest this values? If anyone can give me some example...I'll appreciate...

Comment: What do you mean by "how to nest this values"?

Comment: How to filter inside queries and return all object that contains this word?

Comment: If I need to filter with part of string like "mus", how can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below:

```
function getResult(filterBy, objList) {
  return objList.hightlights.filter(function(obj) {
   return obj.queries.some(function(item){
     return item.indexOf(filterBy) >= 0;
   });
 });
}
```

---

Input#1:

```
getResult("internet", yourObject);
```

Output #1:

```
[{"title":"Fun","url":"fun/index.html","queries":["music","artists","events","internet"]},{"title":"Internet","url":"internet/index.html","queries":["javascript","web","internet"]}]
```

Input #2:

```
getResult("music", yourObject);
```

Output #2:

```
[{"title":"Fun","url":"fun/index.html","queries":["music","artists","events","internet"]}]
```

Comment: Hi @kelsadita, this works, but just with the full string, I want to enter "mus" and works also...how can I did that?

Comment: Hi kelsadita, it works great!!! =)
But let me ask another thing...if the JSON isn't in utf-8, with words like "Pol&iacute;tica", how can I change to utf-8 and compare? =x

Answer (score 0):

```
var search = function(data, query) {
    return data.hightlights.filter(function(highlight) {
        return highlight.queries.indexOf(query) > -1;
    });
}

search(data, "music");
```

---

If you have a `curry` function available (as from **[Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/R.html#curry)**, **[Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/docs#curry)**, etc.) you can wrap this:

```
var search = curry(function(data, query) { ... });
```

And then you can create simpler functions by passing in the data first:

```
highlights = search(data);
//...
highlights("music"); //=> those containing "music"
highlights("internet"); //=> those containing "internet"
```

---

### Update

I know there is already a working solution.  But this might be a bit simpler.

This would search inside the queries for subwords:

```
var search = function(data, query) {
    return data.hightlights.filter(function(highlight) {
        return highlight.queries.filter(function(q) {
            return q.indexOf(query) > -1;
        }).length > 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't this very similar to the previous answer 5 mins ago?

Comment: Hi @scott-sauyet, this works, but just with the full string, I want to enter "mus" and works also...how can I did that?

Comment: @Thrustmaster, yeah, that one came in while I was writing/editing it.  If this one didn't have the currying suggestion I would have just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xyz = {
   "hightlights":[
      {
         "title":"Fun",
         "url":"fun/index.html",
         "queries":[
            "music",
            "artists",
            "events",
            "internet"
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Internet",
         "url":"internet/index.html",
         "queries":[
            "javascript",
            "web",
            "internet",
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

no lets say "var word" contains the keywords to be searched, then you could simply do this:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i in xyz['highlights']){
        var queries = xyz['highlights']['queries'];
        for(j in queries){
              if (word == queries[j]){
                       arr.push(xyz['highlights'][i]);
                       continue;
              }
        }
}
```

arr should have your required object. Sorry this is very basic. But hope it helps.