# Filtering nested js object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get data from a nested  js object  and here is my input.

```js
var data = 
    [ [ { Id: '123', Name: 'Abc', Amount: 110000 } 
      , { Id: '567', Name: 'DEF', Amount:  98000 } 
      , { Id: '345', Name: 'XYZ', Amount: 145000 } 
      ] 
    , [ { Id: '656', Name: 'Abc', Amount: 110000 } 
      , { Id: '223', Name: 'DEF', Amount:  98000 } 
      , { Id: '897', Name: 'XYZ', Amount: 145000 } 
    ] ]
```

And here when I want to get data of `223`.
I am not much aware of how  we can do it in nested  js object .
In regular  js object array, I use the filter method like below.

```
var result= data.filter(element => ((element.Id == "223")).
```

But how Can I do it in case of nested  js object  (in ES6)?

I referred to post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546804/filtering-nested-json-javascript) and made a small fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/62wopk7r/), which isn't working as expected.

Comment: `Id` are unique ? if they are, why don'you use  `find()` method ?

Comment: Nested JSON? You mean an array of arrays with Objects?

Comment: @epascarello original post was JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just flatten it first (first console log), unless you want the whole "outer" array, in which case just do `.find` twice:

```js
var data = [
  [{
      "Id": "123",
      "Name": "Abc",
      "Amount": 110000
    },
    {
      "Id": "567",
      "Name": "DEF",
      "Amount": 98000
    },
    {
      "Id": "345",
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Amount": 145000
    }
  ],
  [{
      "Id": "656",
      "Name": "Abc",
      "Amount": 110000
    },
    {
      "Id": "223",
      "Name": "DEF",
      "Amount": 98000
    },
    {
      "Id": "897",
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Amount": 145000
    }
  ]
];


var result = data.flat().filter(element => element.Id == "223");
console.log(result);

console.log(data.find(el => el.find(item => item.Id === "223")))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `.flat()` the `data` array the first, then just do a simple filter on it and search for the `Id` you want;
or filter array recursively and then search for the `Id` you want.
snippet below demonstrates the second way

```
let result = data.map( array =>  
   array.filter( item => item.Id === "223" )
).flat();
```

```js
var data = 
    [ [ { Id: '123', Name: 'Abc', Amount: 110000 } 
      , { Id: '567', Name: 'DEF', Amount:  98000 } 
      , { Id: '345', Name: 'XYZ', Amount: 145000 } 
      ] 
    , [ { Id: '656', Name: 'Abc', Amount: 110000 } 
      , { Id: '223', Name: 'DEF', Amount:  98000 } 
      , { Id: '897', Name: 'XYZ', Amount: 145000 } 
    ] ];

let result = data.map( array =>  array.filter( item => item.Id === "223" )).flat();


console.log(result);
```