# How do I extract an object from a json file based on a nested value (using JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, object, filter, nested

```
    const data = [
   {0: {id: "1",cat:{string:[{color:"yellow",weight:"10"},{color:"orange",Weight:"10"}]}},
   {1: {id: "1",cat:{string:[{color:"blue",weight:"10"},{color:"orange",Weight:"10"}]}},
   {2: {id: "1",cat:{string:[{color:"white",weight:"10"},{color:"orange",Weight:"10"}]}},
   {3: {id: "1",cat:{string:[{color:"blue",weight:"10"},{color:"orange",Weight:"10"}]}},
]
```

Filter by Color: "Yellow"

Desired Output: `[{0: {id: 1, country: "SA", address: "IOXX",cat:[{color: "yellow",weight: "10"}]}}]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering nested JSON javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546804/filtering-nested-json-javascript)

Comment: Is it possible that `cat` Array has multiple objects? If yes, what would you expect? Should all of the objects have the color of Yellow to return that record? Or if just one of them pass the condition you'll accept that?

Comment: I updated the exact structure in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method

```js
const data = [
    { 0: { id: "1", cat: { string: [{ color: "yellow", weight: "10" }, { color: "orange", Weight: "10" }] } } },
    { 1: { id: "1", cat: { string: [{ color: "blue", weight: "10" }, { color: "orange", Weight: "10" }] } } },
    { 2: { id: "1", cat: { string: [{ color: "white", weight: "10" }, { color: "orange", Weight: "10" }] } } },
    { 3: { id: "1", cat: { string: [{ color: "blue", weight: "10" }, { color: "orange", Weight: "10" }] } } }
];

var res = data.filter((el, i) => data[i][i]['cat']['string'][0]['color'] === 'yellow');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Updated actual structure its has one additional layer of complexity.

Comment: @Powershell-Guy, I made update of my post

Answer (score 0):

You can map over your `data` array and check if each object passes your conditions or not.

```js
const data = [
 {0: {id: 1, country: "SA", address: "IOXX",cat:[{color: "yellow",weight: "10"}]}},
 {1: {id:2, country: "SAP", name: "N", address: "IOP",cat:[{color: "blue",weight: "10"}]}},
 {2: {id:3, country: "S", name: "NO", address: "I",cat:[{color: "blue",weight: "10"}]}},
 {3: {id:4, country: "SXX", name: "NOI", address: "INDIA",cat:[{color: "blue",weight: "12"}]}},
]

const filterByColor = function (color) {
  const filteredCats = []
  data.forEach((item, index) => {
    const hasCorrectColor = item[index].cat.every((cat) => cat.color === color)
    if (hasCorrectColor) {
       filteredCats.push(item)
    }
      
  })
  return filteredCats
}

filterByColor('yellow')
```

Comment: updated to actual structure its got one more layer .